# ASP.NET MVC HTML in User Control vs Raw (no User Control)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, loops, user-controls

Here is my scenario.  I have list of 550 objects (each object represents a Purchase Order) that I need to display on the screen.

I return my List of Purchase Orders to the View and loop over them calling a User Control and pass the object which renders out an HTML div with the contents of the Purchase Order.  This is fine and works ok.

However what I noticed is that if remove the User Control and just print out the same exact HTML (just have the HTML inside the loop instead of inside the UC) I see dramatically slow speeds to fully render the page.

Is ASP.NET doing something differently to render the HTML inside the UC vs just having the raw HTML in the loop?  Does this even make any sense?

Comment: Maybe you would like to post code samples for the two methods you are willing to compare? Otherwise here's my answer: no ASP.NET MVC is not doing anything special when using a normal loop instead of a view control (which by the you should never use in MVC), and the results you are observing are absolutely impossible unless the two things you are comparing are actually not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using StringBuilder or String to hold the HTML and loop over ? Any difference in Results ?
Hopefully there is some Caching/Interning going on inside.

Comment: No didn't really want to go down the route of a string builder as that isn't really maintainable and its a lot of HTML that makes up the div.

Comment: StringBuilder is most recommended eventhout it is complex. String is immutable type and it will create new string object in memory everytime you do string operation. this could be one of the reason for slow performance. check memory usage and you will know. I am sure if you switch it to StringBuilder, it will improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this still doesn't really answer my question.